# Concat Tkey and TValue in a Dictionary in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hello I am trying to Concatenate the values of a Dictionary.

The thing that i want to accomplish is:

Take the TKey and add this to the TValue in the same Dictionary.

Any clue on how to make this work.

Comment: good start to get help is to accept previous answers

Comment: And you also need to provide more context. Do you know the concrete types ? If not, how would you define "add" ?

Comment: You have not provided any useful information here. Are you asking how to concatenate strings? If not, what are you trying to do? What do you want to do with the concatenated strings? And how does it relate to a dictionary object?

Comment: How about some code that would show us what you tried.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you even tried a simple `foreach`? Not everything can be easily concatenated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple enough with LINQ.

```
var result = 
    dictionary
    .Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(), 
        (sb, kv) => 
            sb.AppendFormat(
                "({0}, {1}),", 
                kv.Key, 
                kv.Value
            )
    )
    .ToString()
    .TrimEnd(',');
```

Another route as suggested by @Kirk Woll

```
var result = 
    string.Join(
        ",",
        dictionary
        .Select(kv => string.Format("({0}, {1})", kv.Key, kv.Value))
        .ToArray() // This is not necessary in .NET 4.0
    );
```

Comment: +1. Interesting use of Aggregate. Never thought of doing it this way.

Comment: Hmm, I'd use `string.Join` instead -- that way you avoid the hacky looking `.TrimEnd(',')`.

Comment: @Kirk - That's a good direction to take actually. `Join` will use `unsafe` code so it should perform quite well.

Answer (score 3):

Not totally clear what/why you want this, but this will "add" the value to the key (assuming the '+' operator will work on your key/value types).

```
dictionary.Select(x => x.Key + x.Value)
```

Answer (score 3):

You mean you want a string representation?

I'd go with something like this, if so:

```
public static class KeyValuePairEx
{
    public static string ConcatToString<TKey, TValue>(this KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> source)
    {
        return string.Format("{0} {1}", source.Key, source.Value);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Dictionary<int, string> dict = GetDictionary();

foreach (var entry in dict)
{
    Console.WriteLine(entry.ConcatToString());
}
```